# Perform an automated scp on a Windows server

Tags: windows, ssh

I need to perform an automated scp (every two hours) from a Windows 2012 server to a Linux server. I know how to do it from a Linux server to another Linux server (ssh and cron).

On Windows, what tool do I need? I know ssh is not native on Windows so I would like to use a similar tool.

Comment: SCP? Why not the newer SFTP?

Answer (score 7):

You use WinSCP and windows scheduled tasks.  WinSCP's site has a guide on scripting and automating it: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

You will also have to setup private keys so no password is required.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not know of WinSCP. Good to know it is GPL also.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) utility to handle the file transfer.  Setup an authentication key to be able to login without having to enter a password.

To handle the timing create a scheduled task to execute the pscp command (or a batch file) on the desired schedule.

Answer (score 4):

You can install OpenSSH on the Windows 2012 server. [Here's the relevant page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) on the WinSCP (the SCP client for Windows) website.

Once you've done that, simply set up a cron job from the Linux destination server to fetch the files from the Windows 2012 source server. (It's easier than the other way around, especially because you said you already know how to do that.)

Comment: thanks, if I do the scp from the distant Linux server, why would I need winscp? Other question, is it easy to register the ssh key with OpenSSH to allow the linux server to perform the SCP without entering the password?

Comment: 1) You do not need WinSCP at all, only a SSH server to install on Windows. 2) It should be a trivial task, just read the docs. I don't know if `ssh-copy-id` works also towards a Win server.

Comment: the windows server is not accessible from the outside of the company, but I can access the remote linux server from the windows server. So I wont be able to perform the scp from linux.

Answer (score 1):

Grant probably has the preferred way, but if you don't want to learn WinSCP's scripting language then you can install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) and run `scp` directly. Use Task Scheduler to launch `scp`. (You may have to create an intermediary `.bat` or `.sh` file to actually execute `scp`, depending on the arguments.) You can also set up `sshd` with Cygwin later if you need.

Comment: Cygwin is likely overkill for such a task, unless you have need of other *nix utils. kicken's suggestion of `pscp` is far lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any scriptable Windows SCP (or better SFTP) client.

For example [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) supports both scripting and SCP/SFTP.

See [automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

A simple batch file to upload files with WinSCP looks like:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\path\ftp.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "put c:\local\path\* /remote/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

You can have the [batch file generated by WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you.

---

For scheduling, simply use the Windows Scheduler.
For details see [scheduling file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*